# BIOS Installation problem

Tags: system-installation

I get an error upon installation:

> MP-Bios bug:8254 timer is not connected to IO-APIC

Is this a bad error and if it is how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This error appears to be a minor bug, your hardware vendor may have provided a bios update that may take care of it. In the mean time if you are not experiencing any resulting errors it can be ignored. Otherwise try [adding](https://askubuntu.com/a/38834/723193) either `noioapic` or `nomodeset` boot options.

Answer (score 0):

BIOS isn't a thing you should mess up with.
If you really want to update, go to the mainboard manufacturer's website and download it from there